# What is the max length of page titles for SEO?

Tags: html, seo, search-engine

I would like to know the page title meta tag value limit according to the various search engines like Google, Bing, Yahoo, etc...

**I don't want my users to write bunch of junk words in first, for example, 60 chars and give the needed info, which is important to the search engines, at the end. I need to prevent the important part of the title being chopped off by the search engines.**

There are several questions which are not up to date for today. I would like to create a reference here with up-to-date info with your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO. Probably best to ask on http://webmsaters.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specifically about programming and is thus off-topic as mentioned by the [SEO tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info)

Comment: You're right, sorry. Deleting question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is proper [article](https://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag) for you.

> Optimal Length for Search Engines Google typically displays the first
>   50-60 characters of a title tag, or as many characters as will fit
>   into a 512-pixel display. If you keep your titles under 55 characters,
>   you can expect at least 95% of your titles to display properly. Keep
>   in mind that search engines may choose to display a different title
>   than what you provide in your HTML. Titles in search results may be
>   rewritten to match your brand, the user query, or other
>   considerations.

Hope it will help.